# Nested promises - Mocha - Exceeded timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js

I have got a test failing because of a timeout using Mocha.
I do call the "done()" function but it does not seem to work for some reason.

My test currently looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var mocha = require('mocha');
var calendar = require('./../Server/calendarDatabase');

describe("Calendar", function () {
    describe("Database", function () {
        it("should get stuff from the database", function (done) {
            return calendar.Connect()
            .then(function () {
                return calendar.getAll();
            })
            .then(function (returnValue) {
                expect(returnValue.count).to.equal(5); //This should fail, my database records are 20+
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Where my `calendar.Connect()` and `calendar.getAll()` are both promises:

```
var express = require('express');
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = require('./../config');
var calendarDbConnection = {};

calendarDbConnection.Connect = function() {
    return sql.connect(config.mssql);    
}

calendarDbConnection.getAll = function () {
    var promise =  new sql.Request()
        .query('select * from CalendarTable')
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    return promise;
}

module.exports = calendarDbConnection;
```

However while running my test, I get following output:

[image]

When I call the `done()` after my last `then()`, the function gets resolved but the outcome of my test does not. The number of lines I get from the database are over 20 and I check if they are equal to 5. So, my test should fail, but it does not.

```
//previous code
.then(function (returnValue) {
     expect(returnValue.count).to.equal(5); //This should fail, my database records are 20+
     });
     done();
//...
```

So this last outcome passes my test, while it should not.

What am I missing here? I am calling the callback function but then my expected outcome is not correct.

Comment: You aren't capturing any errors thrown. Add a `.catch` at the end of the chain?

Comment: Updated my question, this works but my test passes in that case. I thought `expect` would make this test fail on itself, without the required catch block.

Comment: Found it! If I catch my `done` in itself it works with the assertion as I expected. i.e. `then(....) { ... done(); }.catch(done);` Thank you for the help, feel free to post this as an answer for me to accept.

Comment: if you want to increase `timeout`, you can use `timeout(10000)`

Comment: The timeout is not the problem in itself, rather the way I catch my outcome.

Comment: Please do not edit solutions in questions. Solutions must be posted as answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since You are returning a Promise from the test, you [should not](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) pass `done` as an argument:

> Alternately, instead of using the done() callback, you may return a Promise. This is useful if the APIs you are testing return promises instead of taking callbacks.

Although you can pass `done` to `catch` call as stated above, it seems more convenient to get rid of `done` and just return a promise.

```
it("should get stuff from the database", function () {
    return calendar.Connect() // returns Promise, so no `done`
    .then(function () {
        return calendar.getAll();
    })
    .then(function (returnValue) {
        expect(returnValue.count).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only pass done in the catch.

```
then(....) { ... done(); }.catch(done);
```

Comment: Much simpler to do what the accepted answer suggests: just return the promise.